# What is the meaning of "pent"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Under the arching heavens of the afternoon swift passing, and the
>   voices of children and women,
>
> The many-moving sea-tides, and I saw the ships how they sail’d,
>
> And the summer approaching with richness, and the fields all busy with
>   labor,
>
> And the infinite separate houses, how they all went on, each with its
>   meals and minutia of daily usages,
>
> And the streets how their throbbings throbb’d, and the cities **pent**—lo, then and there,
>
> Falling upon them all and among them all, enveloping me with the rest,
>
> Appear’d the cloud, appear’d the long black trail,
>
> And I knew death, its thought, and the sacred knowledge of death.

From "[When Lilacs Last in the Dooryard Bloom’d](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45480/when-lilacs-last-in-the-dooryard-bloomd)" by Walt Whitman.

What is the meaning of **pent** here?

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pent) says it is an adjective and another term for pent-up, means:

> 1. unable to be expressed or released.
> 2. Closely confined or held back.

And [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pent):

> shut up : CONFINED, REPRESSED

Comment: Please add a little following context, and an attributed link*. Also which dictionaries haven't given a more logical alternative sense. // *If it's by an old classmate of mine, it's probably just there to sound classy.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I added what you wanted.

Comment: 'Lexico' is well-respected in spite of the funky new name (though it's not as prestigious as its stablemate, OED). / It's got me puzzled, as it doesn't seem to be in balance with its immediate context – I'd expect a finite verb-form. Ah, poetry.

Comment: So lilacs and sea are free in nature, and cities are pent up (cramped) with the hustle and bustle of labor and soot.

Comment: **It is a post-positioned adjective**. As in something like: the cities black, all filled with soot. That kind of thing. So, it's the **pent** cities i.e., confined. As a poet, Walt Whitman for some reason really gets on my nerves. Maybe because he was a bohemian or hippy in an era where there weren't any. So some of his poems sound like a mixture of tea and fish.

Comment: It's an old weak irregular participle of _pen_ (v), a causative meaning 'to cause to come to be in a pen'. It's equivalent to (and pronounced like) _penned_.

Comment: ... pronounced like "penned", except ending with a "t" sound.

Comment: *Pent* also came whole cloth from the French *pente* (meaning sloped), and is quite productive in architecture terminology. It can mean sloped, steeply sloped, all piled up and leaning on each other. I didn't get the "walled in city" impression so much as an image of a piled up and steeply angular hodgepodge. The poem's vantage point is backing off successively from each of the earlier images.

Comment: Does "penthouse" derive its meaning from these roots?

Comment: @JohnCanon from Anglo-French pentiz, a shortening of Old French apentis "attached building, appendage," from Medieval Latin appendicium, from Latin appendere "to hang". Modern spelling is from c. 1530, by folk etymology influence of Middle French pente "slope," and English house (the meaning at that time was "attached building with a sloping roof or awning").